# Rails 4 has_one association form not building

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, actioncontroller, strong-parameters

I need some pointers on how Rails 4 works with has_one and belongs_to association.

My form doesn't save the `has_one` relationship

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates: :body, presence: true

  has_one :category, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**Post Controller**

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.build_category
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

**Form in the Post#new action**

```
<%= form_for @post do |form| %>

  <%= form.label :body %>
  <%= form.text_area :body %>

  <%= fields_for :category do |category_fields| %>
    <%= category_fields.label :title %>
    <%= category_fields.text_field :title %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.button "Add Post" %>

<% end %>
```

It's not saving the `category` title when the Post form is submitted.

**Debug params**

```
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: 08/I6MsYjNUhzg4W+9SWuvXbSdN7WX2x6l2TmNwRl40=
post: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  body: 'The best ice cream sandwich ever'
category: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  title: 'Cold Treats'
button: ''
action: create
controller: posts
```

**App log**

```
Processing by BusinessesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
               "authenticity_token"=>"08/I6MsYjNUhzg4W+9SWuvXbSdN7WX2x6l2TmNwRl40=",
               "post"=>{"body"=>"The best ice cream sandwich ever"},
               "category"=>{"title"=>"Cold Treats", "button"=>""}
```

In the Rails console.. I can run the following succesfully

```
> a = Post.new
=> #<Post id: nil, body: "">
> a.category
=> nil

> b = Post.new
=> #<Post id: nil, body: "">
> b.build_category
=> #<Post id: nil, title: nil>
> b.body = "The best ice cream sandwich ever"
=> "The best ice cream sandwich ever"
> b.category.title = "Cold Treats"
=> "Cold Treats"
```

The questions I have the relates to how to tackle this problem:

1. I'm not sure if I have to add `:category_attributes` in the `post_params` strong parameter method?
2. Should the logs and debug params show that the `Category` attributes
   are nested inside the `Post` parameter?
3. In the `Category` hash parameter there is a blank `button` key that isn't in my `fields_for` am I missing something when using the form helpers?
4. Is the reason because the create action doesn't take the
   `build_category` method and I will need to add this to the create
   action?
5. Will validations on the `Category` model (`presence: true`) be
   automatically used on the `Post` form?

Thanks in advance.

## Update: missing `category_fields` inside `fields_for` block.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Question #1:** Yes, you need to add the `:category_attributes` in the `post_params` strong parameter method like this:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:body, category_attributes: [:title])
end
```

**Question #2:** Yes, the parameters should be nested, this is a typo in your view because you are not applying the `fields_for` (plural by the way) in the scope of the parent form builder, also you are not using the `category_fields` form builder inside the `fields_for` block!

The view should look like this:

```
<%= form_for @post do |form| %>

  <%= form.label :body %>
  <%= form.text_area :body %>

  <%= form.fields_for :category do |category_fields| %>
    <%= category_fields.label :title %>
    <%= category_fields.text_field :title %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.button "Add Post" %>

<% end %>
```

**Question #3:** The button parameter might be in the wrong place due to the mixed up form building in your view.

**Question #4:** You don't need to build the child model in your create action if you accept nested attributes

**Question #5:** Yes, the validation of the child model is also run and if the validation of the child fails, the parent will also have an error and is not saved to the database.

Comment: Sled, you sir are a gentleman. Thank you for pointing out my wrong ways. I have been looking at the same form for days not know that I needed to add form.builder inside the fields_for block. Thanks again for clarifying the strong parameter nested attributes. I really appreciate the time you took to answer all my questions. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

@sled you are right. But for future Rails 4.1 bolded (**) will be deprecated

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit **(:body, :category_attributes => [:title])**
end
```

bolded will be forced to be so **(:body, category_attributes: [:title])**